# Selecting based on criterion on a single column

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have an array that looks like `M = {a, b, c, d}`, where `a, b, c, d` are column vectors. I want to select rows from this array based on the elements in column `c` meeting a specified condition.

For example, if I have

```
M = {{"cat", 21, 10, 1}, {"dog", 7, 42, 2}, {"horse", 30, 1, 19},{"hippo", 99, 15,4}}
```

I want to take rows from this array based on the condition

```
c[[i]] >= 10
```

How could this be done? Ideally I would like to use `Select` as this can retrieve the sublist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feels like a duplicate of a bunch of questions, you could probably find by searching this forum... Some basic structures:

```
Select[M, #[[3]] >= 3 &]
```

> {{"cat", 21, 10, 1}, {"dog", 7, 42, 2}, {"hippo", 99, 15, 4}}

```
Cases[M,x_/;x[[3]]>=3]
```

> {{"cat",21,10,1},{"dog",7,42,2},{"hippo",99,15,4}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Pick[M, UnitStep[M[[All, 3]] - 10], 1]
```

> {{"cat", 21, 10, 1}, {"dog", 7, 42, 2}, {"hippo", 99, 15, 4}}

More general, you may use

```
check = # >= 10 &;
Pick[M, check /@ M[[All, 3]]]
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik; this technique wouldn't work if I exchange entries to arbitrary arrays, so is there perhaps a generalisation? I was thinking something like `Select[M, (#[[All, 3]] >=10) &]` - then (if it worked) the type of element wouldn't matter so much i.e. It could generalise to more complicated criteria